# How to mock function in componentDidUpdate() using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm pretty new to testing React components, and am having trouble with several tests. My component uses componentDidUpdate to trigger a Promise, that, when resolved, sets state with the returned data, as well as setting state loading to false. With the way I am trying to test now, it is always loading. I suppose I am trying to figure out if there is a way to mock the function in componentDidUpdate() so that the state variables are set correctly in the test. Everything works great when not testing! Thanks in advance, and please let me know if you need anything else.

Here is my simplified component:

```
import {getTodos} from '../../utils'

export class App extends React.Component {
  contructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
    toDos: null, 
    loading: true,
   }
};

componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.currentUser !== null) {
   if (this.state.toDos === null) {
    Promise.all([getToDos(this.props.currentUser)].then((response) => {
     const toDos = response[0].data.data
     this.setState({toDos})
     this.setState({loading: false})
    .catch((error) => {
     this.setState({loading: false})
    })
   }
  }
}

render() {
  if(this.state.loading) {
   return <Loader text='Loading data'/>
  }
}


...........
```

And my current test implementation:

```
import {getTodos} from '../../utils'

const TODOS = require ('../../todos.json')

getTodos = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 
  Promise.resolve({
   data: {data: todos.json}
  )}
)

it('renders the ToDos', async() => {
  render(<App />)
  //this times out waiting for 'Loading data' to be removed
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getByText('Loading data')
}
```

I have tried to mock the function getTodos, but not sure if that is sufficient, or what else I need to do.